# Custom Label does not show the Text string

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I needed to make my own label to hold some value, that is diferent from the value displayed to user

```
public class LabelBean : Label {
  private string value;

  public LabelBean(string text = "", string value = ""): base() {
    base.Text = text;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public string Value {
    get { return value; }
    set { this.value = value; }
  }
}
```

but now id in the form constructor I replace the control with my class

```
this.lbAttributeType = new LabelBean();
```

and later after the form is created, but before it is shown I set the text through setter

```
(this.lbAttributeType as LabelBean).Value = value;
this.lbAttributeType.Text = Transform(value);
```

but in the form I have always "label1" text... what is wrong with it?
thanks

**UPDATE**

I added the solution here to find it easier:

```
public class MyLabel : Label {

    public MyLabel()
      : base() {
    }

    public string Value {
      set {
        this.Text = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

and the form with Widnows.Forms.Label label1 control

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Controls.Remove(this.label1);
      this.label1 = new MyLabel();
      this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
      (this.label1 as MyLabel).Value = "oh";
    }
  }
```

the bug was in the `Controls.Remove` and `Controls.Add`,
thanks all for their time :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast in order to set the property (`(this.lbAttributeType as LabelBean).Value = value;`). If you have to, then there is something wrong with your code. Casts hide errors, not fix them.

Comment: As Cody said, `lbAttributeType` should actually be of `LabelBean` type.

Comment: I'd guess you put the code in the constructor *before* the InitializeComponent() call.  And that you see a first chance exception in the Output window.

Comment: no the initialization comes first, @CodyGray - why? the label is classic winforms Label and in that I put my LableBean... than the casting is neccessery couse in the label is actualy the labelbean object.. this is polymorfism isnt it?

Comment: No, that's not what polymorphism is. The label isn't a WinForms Label, it's your custom label. But it's obviously not being defined as an object of that type, or else you wouldn't have to cast it. And since it's not declared as an object of that type, it doesn't have those properties.

Comment: @CodyGray see my update... maybe you can be concrete but i think this should work, and you has to cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with WoLfulus and Andreas Zoltan and would add a symmetrical functionality to Text if there exists a unambiguous reverse transformation:

```
public string Value
{
    get { return value; }
    set
    {
        if (this.value != value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.Text = Transform(value);
        }
    }
}

public override string Text
{
    get { return base.Text; }
    set
    {
        if (base.Text != value) {
            base.Text = value;
            this.value = TransformBack(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `if` checks in order to avoid an endless recursion.

---

EDIT:

Assigning your label to `lbAttributeType` is not enough. You must remove the old label from the Controls collection **before** the assignment and re-add it **after** the assignment.

```
this.Controls.Remove(lbAttributeType);  // Remove old label
this.lbAttributeType = new LabelBean(); 
this.Controls.Add(lbAttributeType); // Add new label
```

Your form was still displaying the old label! Why did I not see it earlier?

Comment: Nice touch with the endless recursion check.

Comment: +1 Well done Olivier - controls collection of course - @Zavael I strongly suggest you drag-drop the control using the toolbox, after adding a default constructor, though - it would solve all these problems.

Comment: Yes, or you can open MyForm.designer.cs and replace `Label` by `LabelBean` where appropriate and then remove the code in the constructor. This replaces the normal label with your user control without having to alter your form in the designer.

Comment: thanks for the controls, you were faster than wolfulus :) ill try it at monday, thanks for now

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Create a new delegate outside the label class:

   ```
   public delegate string LabelFormatDelegate( string val );
   ```
2. Add this to your label class:

   ```
   public LabelFormatDelegate ValueFormatter = null;

   public string Value 
   {
       get 
       { 
           return value; 
       }
       set 
       { 
           this.value = value; 
           if (this.ValueFormatter != null)
           {
               this.Text = this.ValueFormatter(value); // change the label here
           }
           else
           {
               this.Text = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Place a new common label to your form (lets name it "label1")
4. Goto to Form1.Designer.cs and search for "label1" declaration.
5. Rename the "Label" type to your own label type (Ex: "MyLabel")
6. Change the initialization code of label on **InitializeComponent** function on designer code to match the new type "MyLabel"

   Example:

   ```
   this.label1 = new Label();
   ```

   Change to:

   ```
   this.label1 = new MyLabel();
   ```
7. In the Form_Load event, specify the format function:

   ```
   this.label1.ValueFormatter = new LabelFormatDelegate(this.Transform);
   ```

Notes: You'll need to remove the "Text" setter call too from here:

```
(this.lbAttributeType as LabelBean).Value = value;
// this.lbAttributeType.Text = Transform(value);
```

This will keep your value/text in sync but remember not to set "Text" property by hand.

Comment: dont want to chain the label class with transform function, as the funcion is a bit more complicated with more parameters, that are not known in the label class, only on the form class, either way a dont see the difference, but thanks

Comment: @Zavael - the difference is that this at least ensures that `Text` is automatically kept in sync with your `Value`.  If the form has all the knowledge, then encapsulating this functionality in a standalone control type might not be suitable.

Comment: @Zavael You can set a callback delegate for the format function if you want. This will make the label reusable for any "formatted" texts that depends on "value". By looking at your code we can't do anything else than just guessing the problem beucase your code seems "right".

Comment: @Zavael I've added the "callback" example too. I've not tested the code but it should work as expected.

Comment: not working... i did an simple example

public delegate string LabelFormatDelegate(string val);

  public class MyLabel : Label {

    public LabelFormatDelegate ValueFormatter = null;

    public MyLabel()
      : base() {
    }

    public string Value {
      set {
        if (this.ValueFormatter != null) {
          this.Text = this.ValueFormatter(value);
        }
      }
    }
  }

with form in next comment

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.label1 = new MyLabel();
      (this.label1 as MyLabel).ValueFormatter = new LabelFormatDelegate(Getstr);
      (this.label1 as MyLabel).Value = "oh";
    }

    public string Getstr(string value) {
      return value + " - hahaha";
    }
  }

shit it is not formatted :(( but it is not working either :(

Comment: You can't do this: **this.label1 = new MyLabel();** because you're loosing the reference to the original label class (which is already added to the form controls) plus the current one is not coming to your form because it's not being added to the control list. Go to the InitializeComponent() function and change the initialization of label1 (which is something like **this.label1 = new Label()**) there.

Comment: I've edited the reply with all the "steps" to get it working right.

Comment: ooo I dint realize this, I will try this monday at work, it seems to be the problem u have +1 for your time and effort for now, thanks :)

Comment: @Zavael it is called "best" answer, not first, neither faster. Oliver and Andras gave you good answers too, but keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is because, since you're doing the work in the constructor, the `InitializeComponent` code, automatically generated by the designer, is overwriting the control instance, as it's most likely called after your initialisation.

If the class is part of the project, you will find it on the toolbox; meaning you can simply drag and drop your new control on the form in place of the existing one - this is what you should do.

This ensures that the designer-generated property is of your `LabelBean` type, and not simply `Label`.

Also - you should consider changing your `Value` setter as demonstrated by WoLfulus (+1 there)

### Update

In response to the comment you put on WoLfulus' answer - here's a couple of alternatives:

1) If the form is the 'clever' bit here - consider just writing a helper method in it, and setting the value of the label through it, leveraging the `Tag` property:

```
public void SetLabelBean(Label target, string value)
{
  Label.Tag = value;
  Label.Text = Transform(value);
}

public string GetLabelBean(Label target)
{
  return target.Tag as string;
}
```

2) Continue using your sub-classed `LabelBean` type (adding it via the designer as I've already mentioned) - but use an abstraction to give it access to the form's `Transform` method:

```
public interface ITransformProvider
{
  string Transform(string);
}
```

Make your form class implement this interface, with the `Transform` method you elude to.

Now, in your `LabelBean` class:

```
public ITransformProvider Transformer
{
  get{
    //searches up the control hierarchy to find the first ITransformProvider.
    //should be the form, but also allows you to use your own container controls
    //to change within the form.  The algorithm could be improved by caching the
    //result, invalidating it if the control is moved to another container of course.
    var parent = Parent;
    ITransformProvider provider = parent as ITransformProvider;
    while(provider == null){
      parent = parent.Parent;
      provider = parent as ITransformProvider;
    }
    return provider;
  }
}
```

And then, finally, using WoLfulus' code, but slightly changed, you can do this:

```
public string Value          
{         
  get          
  {          
    return value;          
  }         
  set          
  {          
    this.value = value; 
    var transformer = Transformer;
    if(transformer != null) this.Text = transformer.Transform(value);
  }         
}
```

That, I think, addresses your issues with that answer.

Comment: the creation of the LabelBean is after the initializeComponent, so it shouldnt by the case, but with the tool draging on the form i was unsuccesful, it throw an error on me with missingMethodException: Constructor on type LabelBean not found' at System.Runtipe.CreateInstanceImpl(Bindingflags.... etc it is a long stacktrace... could that be the problem?

Comment: @Zavael - You need to ensure that there is a default constructor on your control type.  Also, see my updated answer which provides a version that strikes a balance between the subclassed control and the `Transform` code needing to be in the form.

Comment: as i understanded the updated version, the first one is the same assigning of transfomed value to the label.Text value and in the second i need to call transform in the label class, whitch i cant, because the label class can not fill all the parameters in the transform funcion...
I am really surprised that simple assigning of text value in subclass is not working...
but thanks for your time, i tried a simpler project with simple transform function for wolfulus and it is not working either

Comment: @Zavael - the second solution allows you to hide the true nature of your `Transform` operation behind an interface that you can implement in the form, thus hiding the complexity from the label.  This also allows you to change the implementation according to each form, and even (because the control tree is walked) according to the physical structure of the form and any containers it has.  *That's* polymorphism :)

Comment: all right, i will try it if Wolfs will not work, +1 for your time and effort for now, thanks a lot :)